# Problema com a chave da API do Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

O Mapa não abre no dispositivo real usando o `.apk` gerado.

Fiz a `Activity` para o Mapa usando o assistente do AS para esta finalidade, neste modo ele gera uma o `SH1`. Fui no Google API onde eu já possuo uma conta e um projeto e então gerei uma chave que coloquei no meu projeto e tudo funcionando corretamente!

Com o projeto terminado,  gerei uma *Key Store*, peguei o `SH1` gerei uma nova chave, voltei ao Google API, retirei o `SHA1` de *Debug* e coloquei a nova. Pedi para gerar uma nova chave porém, vi que nada mudou ou seja a chave foi a mesma!

Gerei o `.apk` e o mapa não aparece!

Deixei de fazer algo que deveria?  Pulei alguma etapa?

Comment: Exibe alguma mensagem no Console? Gere o apk assinado, e deixe o smartphone conectado no USB (Debugando, com o Android Studio) e veja se exibe algum erro de chave quando abre a tela!

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente para criar credenciais para acessar suas APIs ativadas, [consulte os detalhes na documentação da API](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158857?hl=pt_BR). Segundamente, vou te dar umas dicas abaixo:

## Criar Chave de API

**Passo 1:** Impressão digital para certificação `SHA-1`

Para adquirir a impressão digital para certificação SHA-1, você tem que entrar no console do seu computador e realizar o seguinte comando:

> keytool -list -v -keystore c
>   :\Users\MyNameUser\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

FORMATO: `5D:C1:0B:2E:E2:91:C3:BB:3E:60:6A:8A:3E:8D:56:C1:0A:C6:36:B2`

**Passo 2:** Criar a sua chave API

Para criar a sua chave API, visite o Console APIs em https://code.google.com/apis/console e faça login com sua conta do Google.

FORMATO: `AIzaSyAi6j8jukil9XnoWzeAsB1Fgr1CQkq9Yk8`

Observe a imagem abaixo como seve ser configurado corretamente.

### Imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Criar IDs do cliente OAuth 2.0

Você tem que gerar uma **Impressão digital do certificado de autorização**

Adicione o nome do seu pacote e a impressão digital do certificado de *login* `SHA-1` para restringir o uso aos seus aplicativos para Android. [Veja aqui](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158849?hl=pt_BR#installedapplications&android).

Observe abaixo como tem que estar configurado:

### Imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Apesar de toda configuração, é importante fazer o download do `google-services.json` [disponibilizado pelo Google Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) e salvar dentro da pasta APP no seu projeto.

### No Manifest.xml

Já na sua aplicação, você deve inserir seus `meta-data`'s desta forma:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

PS.: **Não** esqueça de conceder permissão para acesso a internet `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: Boa tarde, obrigado pelos comentários, eu como descrevi já tinha uma chave e estava tudo ok no ambiente de Desenvolvimento, gerei uma keystore e dai pra frente é que deu bronca, o que eu fiz foi conforme orientado deixei o smart em modo de debug e fui observando o log no AE, o que eu fiz agora foi ir no console do Google e gerei uma nova chave, usando a SHA-1 gerada pelo meu keystore até porque no log eu consigo ver

Comment: Robson, você chegou a gerar o google-services.json e jogar dentro da pasta app?

Comment: Não, este ai eu nem sabia meu caro, mais deixa continuar que eu errei aqui no comentario anterior, no log do AE eu consigo ver "Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure" e ali no log vejo também o SHA-1 do meu keystore, gerei nova chave, coloquei no meu manifesto mais ainda nada o erro no console do AE é o mesmo, agora sobre este google service json não, nem sabia disto

Comment: @Robson Esse procedimento todo ai eu fiz aqui num app meu publicado na loja e funciona perfeitamente. Eu cheguei a ter esse seu mesmo problema, mas ai resolvi.

Comment: mas no meu caso, como debug não tive problema nenhum, só na hora que enviei pra loja que não aparecia o map. Ai refiz tudo novamente seguindo esses procedimentos e funfou bunito.

Comment: @Robson editei inserindo como você deve colocar no seu manifest.xml

Comment: Prezados boa tarde,achei o problema, no meu caso eu gerei o mapa usando o assistente do AE, ele gera um arquivo google_maps_api.xml, só que este cara fica em uma pasta debug do meu projeto, só que tem outro carinha deste na pasta release, e tu não vê este arquivo e esta pasta, talvez os senhores não tiveram este problema porque colocam a chave literalmente no manifesto, então coloquei a chave no arquivo correto e agora deu certo, num precisou ai do g-services.json mais obrigado ai a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Em produção, caso você utilize Google Play App Signing, você pode encontrar facilmente o SHA-1 em:

https://play.google.com/apps/publish/ > Clique no seu app > Gerenciamento de versão > Assinatura de Apps > Certificado de assinatura do app

Siga também o procedimento também por [@Viana](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/35406/viana) para que você possa usar a api em modo debug (pelo emulador por exemplo)